# Replacing Characters Using Numbers

Tags: word-usage

I was playing an online game and I noticed a player on my team with username "4PP13". I asked him what should I call him. He said "apple".

I didn't have second thoughts until I Googled it. It turned out "4PP13" does means apple according to [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/4pp13).

So what's the deal? Is this a special case? If not, what is this called?

Comment: It's called "*leetspeak"* (variously *733tsp34k* etc), where "leet" is a foreshortening of "elite", as these kids have been styling themselves since at least the mid-90s (which is when I, personally, first encountered it).

Comment: It's like teenage slang; if you get it, you're in the gang. If you don't, you're a loser. No big deal unless you wanna hang with somebody that's 2 1337 2 CU

Comment: It should probably be explicitly noted somewhere that leetspeak is generally considered to be fairly obnoxious, and, as such, is almost always used ironically these days. Consider your friend apple an internet-hipster, if you will.

Comment: @webbcode It should be noted - I just got kicked out of a game.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I asked this on asked Jun 19 at 15:24 and he asked it on asked Jul 23 at 10:07. If I remember correctly, June comes before July?

Comment: What you could have done was to post a comment stating that you had asked an almost identical question a month earlier. I'm choosing what appears to me the most popular question and answer. That's all, seeing as the two are equally good.

Comment: Okay, I understand your reasoning, and I agree there should not be duplicates. I'm justing wondering if the fact that that post has more views and more votes can be the reason to do this.

Comment: Well, I didn't. And yes, I feel partially responsible for that. But it happened. I don't come here every day, and I doubt this isn't going to happen in the future. So if we(though I doubt we can) establish that this is the proper way to go if this happens again, I'd feel privileged to help prevent further trouble in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of [Leetspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Leet), a relatively common internet pseudo-language/alphabet from a few years ago.

> Leet (or "1337"), also known as eleet or leetspeak, is an alternative alphabet for the English language that is used primarily on the Internet. It uses various combinations of ASCII characters to replace Latinate letters. For example, leet spellings of the word leet include 1337 and l33t; eleet may be spelled 31337 or 3l33t.
>
> *www.wikipedia.com*

Comment: Leetspeak originated in English-language texts, but its approach to orthography has also imported to other languages.  In other Latin-alphabet texts that substitutions are often the same.  I've also seen the same principles adapted to express Cyrillic in software systems that are Latin-only, such as text chat in Quake and Quake World.

Comment: c00l! A1s0 f0und [this](http://blog.dictionary.com/texting-leet/) b10g p0s7 by Dictionary.com 4nd [this](http://www.robertecker.com/hp/research/leet-converter.php) c0nv3r73r